# Is is possible to simplify the expression $\arctan(y)-\arctan(x)=c$

Tags: trigonometry

Is is possible to simplify the expression $\arctan(y)-\arctan(x)=c$.

I tried writing the expression in the form $\frac{\arcsin(y)}{\arccos(y)}-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\arccos(x)}=c$ but it does not lead to anyting. How do I reduce it I want to eliminate $\arctan$ from the expression.

Comment: It wouldn't lead to anything, because what you wrote is plain wrong.

Comment: Arctan  $\ne $ arcsin/arccos.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\theta_1 = \arctan (y)$ and  $\theta_2 = \arctan (x)$, we have 
$$ \theta_1 - \theta_2 = c.$$
So 
$$ \tan(c) = \tan(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = \frac{\tan(\theta_1) - \tan(\theta_2)}{1 + \tan(\theta_1)\tan(\theta_2)} = \frac{y - x}{1 + xy}.$$